# Number of Non-NaN Rows in a 3D Matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `3D` matrix with `NaN` padded to obtain equal number of rows in each `2D` matrix i.e each `(:,:,ind)`. Now i need to find the number of actual non-NaN rows in each `(:,:,ind)`.

A simple example of what I need:

```
% Input:
A(:,:,1) = [ 1   1; 
             2   2;
            NaN NaN];
A(:,:,2) = [ 2   2; 
            NaN NaN;
            NaN NaN];
% Function call:
B = callingfunction(A);

% Output:
B = [2 1] % Number of Non-NaN rows in each 2D Matrix
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach #1

```
B = squeeze(sum(all(~isnan(A),2),1))
```

Here's the build-up process to get a hang of it -

**Start>>> Given A:**

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     2     2
   NaN   NaN
A(:,:,2) =
     2     2
   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN
```

**1) Detect all non-NaN positions:**

```
>> ~isnan(A)
ans(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     1     1
     0     0
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     1
     0     0
     0     0
```

**2) Find rows with `all` non-Nan elements:**

```
>> all(~isnan(A),2)
ans(:,:,1) =
     1
     1
     0
ans(:,:,2) =
     1
     0
     0
```

**3) Sum up the number of all such rows:**

```
>> sum(all(~isnan(A),2),1)
ans(:,:,1) =
     2
ans(:,:,2) =
     1
```

**4) Get the result as a 1D array:**

```
>>  squeeze(sum(all(~isnan(A),2),1))
ans =
     2
     1
```

---

### Approach #2

```
B = squeeze(sum(~any(isnan(A),2),1))
```

Use the same *break-up-my-code-into-pieces* process as listed earlier here and in all your future MATLAB codes and all past MATLAB codes that didn't make sense to do so now!

Comment: I'm not getting how it works. would you mind explaining that?

Comment: @SanthanSalai Added comments!